# Recursively merge objects with corresponding property names

Tags: object-oriented, recursion, coffeescript

I have such objects that I need to merge:

> ```
> defaultConditions = 
>   where: 
>     enabled: true
>     acc_id: 
>       ne: null
>
> conditions = 
>   where:
>     id: 2
>     acc_id: 
>       ne: 5
> ```

[This helper recipe](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/helpers.html#section-9), which replaces `where` from `defaultConditions` with `where` from `conditions`, is not quite right for this purpose. So I wrote this:

```
extend = (object, properties) ->
  for key, val of properties
    if val?.constructor is Object and object[key]?.constructor is Object
      object[key] = extend object[key], val
    else
      object[key] = val
  object
```

How can it be improved?